# Do I have to disclose the exchange program of participating student as funding in a paper?

Tags: publications, funding, internship, conflict-of-interest, student-exchange

I am currently writing a paper together with an exchange student of an international academic internship program. As it is common practice, I disclose the research grant, which funds my work. However, the student is paid by the exchange program. He did most of the work and is first author. I am his supervisor and continuously guided his work, though.

Would it be required or is it good practice to disclose the source of his payment or is the grant of my superordinated research project sufficient?

Comment: Why not? It costs nothing to add. Withholding acknowledgements has no advantages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's good manners to acknowledge all sources of funding, and in some cases, may actually be mandated by the funding body. It also costs nothing to add a sentence in the acknowledgements, so overall you should certainly acknowledge the student's funding.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you've benefitted from this internship program (it brought you a student who does successful work who you didn't have to pay!).

Not only should you acknowledge this funding as good manners and perhaps a required policy, you should be eager to do so as a way to credit the program for this benefit!